# Navigating and parsing a JSON tree in Expressjs for Parse.com

Tags: javascript, json, express, parse-platform

Currently a JSON object is being sent to my webhook that I'm building on Parse.com's cloud hosting.

This is the array:

```
{
  "name": "Kenpom",
  "count": 351,
  "frequency": "Every 15 mins",
  "version": 211,
  "newdata": false,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "lastsuccess": "Tue Mar 03 2015 21:29:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "nextrun": "Wed Mar 04 2015 02:38:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionrun": "Tue Mar 03 2015 21:29:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "rank": "1",
        "team": {
          "href": "http://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Kentucky",
          "text": "Kentucky"
        },
        "conference": {
          "href": "http://kenpom.com/conf.php?c=SEC",
          "text": "SEC"
        },
        "currentrecord": "29-0",
        "pyth": ".9792",
        "offensiveefficiency": "118.7",
        "defensiveefficiency": "84.9",
        "tempo": "63.6"
      },
      {
        "rank": "2",
        "team": {
          "href": "http://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Virginia",
          "text": "Virginia"
        },
        "conference": {
          "href": "http://kenpom.com/conf.php?c=ACC",
          "text": "ACC"
        },
        "currentrecord": "28-1",
        "pyth": ".9654",
        "offensiveefficiency": "112.3",
        "defensiveefficiency": "84.0",
        "tempo": "58.2"
      },...
```

And this is what I'm trying to use to accept the request:

```
// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

app.post('/notify_message',
         // express.basicAuth('', ''),
         function(req, res, data) {
  // Use Parse JavaScript SDK to create a new message and save it.
  var Kenpom = Parse.Object.extend("Kenpom");
  var kenpom = new Kenpom();
  kenpom.save({ 
    conference : data,
    rank: data
  }).then(function(kenpom) {
    res.send('Success');
  }, function(error) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send('Error');
  });
});

// Attach the Express app to Cloud Code.
app.listen();
```

I'm getting a 200 on the request, but in Parse, all I'm seeing for the results in the rank and conference values are **{}**

[image: Parse.com]

My question is: How do I navigate through the JSON tree in Express so that I'm getting all these teams with the values from the JSON object getting passed?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to accept the request object, and parse it as json:

Use this at the beginning:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then process the data properly:

```
function (req, res) {
    req.body // req.body is the object that you received
}
```

Comment: does req.body go in kenpom.save? I'm getting an error when I put it in that function

Comment: @beaconhill Try doing `console.log(req.body)`. It should print the JSON object that is sent to you.

Comment: This is a middleware webhook I'm building. It's a URL that a service hits to send it a JSON object when the data is updated. I'm not sure how to debug it.